# VMWARE VSphere VIX clone function

Tags: c#, vmware, vsphere, vix

I have problem with cloning a virtual machine using VMware VIX api in C#. I am using following code to do so and getting following error.

Code:

```
VMWareVirtualHost virtualhost = new VMWareVirtualHost();

virtualhost.ConnectToVMWareVIServer("ip", "username", "password");

VMWareVirtualMachine vm = virtualhost.Open("Machine path");

Console.WriteLine("vm is open");

vm.Clone(VMWareVirtualMachineCloneType.Full, "CLone path");
```

I am getting this error:

> operation is not supported.

Comment: What's your question? There are many conditions that can make a VM un-clonable.